# C++(11/14) intercalate implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, generics, c++14

I wrote a simple generic `intercalate` function (that should be semantically equivalent to the Haskell [intercalate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v%3aintercalate)).

```
template <typename Fwd_It, typename Out_It>
    auto intercalate(Fwd_It first, Fwd_It last, Out_It destFirst,
                     Fwd_It whatFirst, Fwd_It whatLast) {
        if (first == last) return destFirst;
        *destFirst = *first;
        ++first;
        ++destFirst;

        while (first != last) {
            std::copy(whatFirst, whatLast, destFirst);
            *destFirst = *first;
            ++first;
        }
        return destFirst;
    }
```

It appears to be working with what I've tested with (empty ranges, different iterator-supporting ranges, different types, etc.).

However, is this:

- generic enough?
- clean enough?
- fast enough?

Answer (score 4):

I would not cram in the `if` statement like that:

> ```
> auto intercalate(Fwd_It first, Fwd_It last, Out_It destFirst,
>                  Fwd_It whatFirst, Fwd_It whatLast) {
>     if (first == last) return destFirst;
>     *destFirst = *first;
>     // ...
> ```

While this style is okay at times, it may not be too readable in all situations.  Single-line statements can still use curly braces, especially if it may need to be maintained.  You could also add a new line before the line that follows it.

```
auto intercalate(Fwd_It first, Fwd_It last, Out_It destFirst,
                 Fwd_It whatFirst, Fwd_It whatLast) {
    if (first == last) {
        return destFirst;
    }

    *destFirst = *first;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 3):

- it looks like you are missing `++destFirst` in the loop body (or have a stray `++destFirst` in the introductory part?).
- if I understand Haskell semantics, `*first` is itself a list. `*destFirst = *first;` doesn't seem to be enough.
- I'd try to implement `intercalate` in terms of `concat` and `intersperse`, which seem to be important enough to be implemented separately.
- `destFirst` doesn't look right (First implies Last); just `dest` is a better choice.